# Lightning Combobox using elements from an apex class

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have the following functions

**Apex**

```
public class SchedulableClasses {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<ApexClass> SchedulableClasses(){

        ApexClass[] schedulableClasses = (ApexClass[])
  [FIND 'implements schedulable' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(NamespacePrefix, Name)][0];

ApexClass[] realSchedulables = new ApexClass[0];
for(ApexClass klass: schedulableClasses) {
  try {
    Object t = JSON.deserialize('{}', 
      klass.NamespacePrefix == null? 
        Type.forName(klass.Name):
        Type.forName(klass.NamespacePrefix, klass.Name));
    if(t instanceOf Schedulable) {
      realSchedulables.add(klass);
    }
  } catch(TypeException e) {
    // Ignore
  }
}
    return realSchedulables;
    }
}
```

The first function gets for me a list of apex classes that are schedulable 
**HTML**

```html
<template>
<div>
    <lightning-combobox placeholder="Select Apex Class" options={apexOptions} value={value} onchange={handleApexChange}></lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to put these values in this combobox with the help of javascript

**JS**

```js
 handleApexChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
    get apexOptions() {
        return [
            apexclass.forEach(element => {
                label: this.apexclass.data.Name, value:this.apexclass.data.name

            });
        ]
    }
```

So I tried getting inside the List of apex classes that i have. In order to define the labels and values i want to give. But the problem here is the calling for the elements in the javascript since there's more then one element i need to use for or foreach, but the way to call the apex elements from javascript i think it is wrong.

PS the import the and wire methods exist in the javascript they are not missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apex class has no problem. Import track and your class in LWC js file. Then use below code inside the class:

```
@track apexOptions = [];
connectedCallback() {
    getSchedulableClasses()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('result => ', JSON.stringify(result));
            this.apexOptions = result.map((cls) => Object.assign({}, { label: cls.Name, value: cls.Name }));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('error => ', error); // use proper error handling
        });
}
handleApexChange(event) {
    alert(event.detail.value);
}
```

You should call the apex method as a function. It returns a promise which you can handle using then.catch methods.

What you implemented below:

```
get apexOptions() {
    return [
        apexclass.forEach(element => {
            label: this.apexclass.data.Name, value:this.apexclass.data.name

        });
    ]
}
```

This is getter method (I dont understand what exactly you implemented in it - apexclass is not defined). To put it in simple words this is equivalent to formulas in Aura - {!v.firstName+' '+v.lastName}. The same in LWC will be:

```
get name() {
   return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

Note: I used apex imperatively. However you can use wired property or function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in

```
<lightning-combobox placeholder="Select Apex Class" 
options={apexOptions} value={value} onchange={handleApexChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

you should replace the placeholders, e.g. onchange={!c.handleApexChange} (mind the "!c." bit).

In JS, you should define an action and enqueue it to retrieve data from database. Cf. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/salesforce_developer_workshop/creating_lc_with_apex_controller

Comment: I already have the function that I'm using that gets what i want from database. Since it is SOSL i used the apex class that i stated before.